# Is there a way to map a list of dicts according to the dict keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like

```
[{'n': 3, 'topic': 4, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 72, 'topic': 1, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 46, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 36, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 5, 'topic': 4, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 29, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 102, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 13, 'topic': 8, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 52, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 24, 'topic': 5, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}]
```

I want to be able to combine all dicts that have the same `topic` and `shared_via_twitter` values into one and update the `n` value of the new dict to reflect the sum.

e.g
if I have

```
[{'n': 3, 'topic': 1, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 7, 'topic': 1, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}]
```

Then I want `{'n': 10, 'topic': 1, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}` as the result.

I was thinking of using a map something like

```
def xs(x):
    # {'n': 3, 'topic': 4, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}
    # {'n': 7, 'topic': 4, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}
    if x['topic'] == v['topic'] and x['shared_via_twitter'] == v['shared_via_twitter']:
        x['n']+=v['n']
        v = dict(x)
        return x

g = map(xs, rows)
```

but this clearly doesn't look clean/work.
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a mapping operation. it isn't clear what you attempt was doing, exactly, because `v` is not defined. But basically, `map` is not the best tool, because that applies a function to each element, you want to group by your key and aggregate the values of `"n"` with summation. Use the dictionary grouping idiom:

```
>>> data = [{'n': 3, 'topic': 4, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 72, 'topic': 1, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 46, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 36, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 5, 'topic': 4, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 29, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 102, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 13, 'topic': 8, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y'}, {'n': 52, 'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}, {'n': 24, 'topic': 5, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N'}]
>>> grouper = {}
>>> for d in data:
...     key = d['topic'], d['shared_via_twitter']
...     grouper[key] = grouper.get(key, 0) + d['n']
...
>>> grouper
{(4, 'N'): 8, (1, 'Y'): 72, (2, 'N'): 98, (2, 'Y'): 167, (8, 'Y'): 13, (5, 'N'): 24}
```

You can convert this to your final form with:

```
>>> [dict(topic=t, shared_via_twitter=s, n=n) for (t, s), n in grouper.items()]
[{'topic': 4, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N', 'n': 8}, {'topic': 1, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y', 'n': 72}, {'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N', 'n': 98}, {'topic': 2, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y', 'n': 167}, {'topic': 8, 'shared_via_twitter': 'Y', 'n': 13}, {'topic': 5, 'shared_via_twitter': 'N', 'n': 24}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want done, try `collections.defaultdict` or `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

totals = collections.Counter()
for d in data:
   totals[d['topic'], d['shared_via_twitter']] += d['n']
```

That'll leave it in a structure like `{(1, 'N'): 10}` which you can either use as-is, or convert into the list-of-dicts form:

```
converted = [
    {'n': n, 'topic': topic, 'shared_via_twitter': shared_via_twitter}
    for (topic, shared_via_twitter), n in totals.items()
]
```